# I'm having trouble with changing the UI text when colliding with a player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class PointSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb1;
    public Rigidbody2D rb2;
    public TextMeshProUGUI plr1T;
    public TextMeshProUGUI plr2T;
    public float UIVal1 = 1f;

    void Start()
    {
        plr1T = FindObjectOfType<TextMeshProUGUI>();
        plr2T = FindObjectOfType<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerAI")
        {
            UpdateUI();
        }  
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
        plr1T.text = (UIVal1.ToString());
        UpdateFloat();
    }
    
    void UpdateFloat()
    {
        UIVal1 = +1f;
    }

}
```

I want to change the UI text once they collide with an object and increase the value so if they hit it again the number in the text increases. It also does not show any errors. Please help.

I have tried using the ToString() method but it still does not change the text.

Comment: `UIVal1 = +1f;` sets the value of UIVal1 to positive 1.  I believe you meant to use `+= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I see few minor errors from your code:

1. FindObjectOfType returns the first active loaded object that matches the specified type. It returns null if no Object matches the type. Since you have your plr1T and plr2T set in public, you can just assign them in the inspector. If you do that, you can remove the codes from your Start() method. Check the documentation here:
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html
2. This is not really an error, but a best practice. After checking for tags, you can do a null check to avoid Exception error.

You can do:

```
if(other.gameObect != null)
```

Before calling this code:

```
UpdateUI();
```

3. If you're incrementing by 1, you can do: UIVal1++, or UIVal1 += 1.

Comment: I have changed up the code a bit but it still does not change the UI.

Comment: Can I see your new code? How are you assigning the references for plr1T and plr2T?

Answer (score -1):

You made a mistake when incrementing the UIVAL1,
the is the right way :

```
void UpdateFloat()
        {
            UIVal1 = UIVal1 +1;
        }
```

Comment: Even though it's only a few lines of code, consider adding some form of explanation of where the OP went wrong.  Some things can be quite suttle and may require readers to stare at it to determine what has changed.   _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_